# NHibernate 3.2 | Trigger Sequence Identity for Oracle | Loquacious config

Tags: oracle, nhibernate

Does anyone know if the trigger sequence id scenario is supported by the loquacious configuration with NHibernate 3.2 on Oracle database.

I've try both sequence and native as Generators for my id. But it does not support the scenario where my id is generated by a before trigger on Oracle.

With those 2 generators, NHibernate try to push an ID using a call to "Select Sequence.Next From Dual".

Thanks
Phil

Comment: In all honesty the built in configuration stuff for NH is pretty stinky.  You'd be much better off looking at Fluent NH IF you can handle only having NH 3.1 (for now is my understanding..)

Answer (score 3):

You just need to implement `IGeneratorDef`. Something like:

```
public class TriggerIdentityGeneratorDef : IGeneratorDef
{
    public string Class
    {
        get { return "trigger-identity"; }
    }

    public object Params
    {
        get { return null; }
    }

    public Type DefaultReturnType
    {
        get { return typeof (int); }
    }

    public bool SupportedAsCollectionElementId
    {
        get { return true; }
    }
}
```

Comment: You just saved the day!